# correction for mysql query of rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While executing the below mysql query in rails

```
cnt = Domainurl.find_by_sql ["SELECT Max(`count`)FROM `domainurls` WHERE `domaindetail_id`= ?",@domain.id]
urlcr=Domainurl.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM `domainurls` WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ? AND `count` = ?",cnt.count]
urlcr.each do |cr|
  puts cr.url
end
```

I am getting error :

```
"error is: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is at your last query

```
urlcr=Domainurl.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM `domainurls` WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ? AND `count` = ?",cnt.count]
```

you try to find something by 2 parameters ( `domaindetail_id` and `count`) but you provide only `count`. (you must provide domaindetail_id too)

```
urlcr=Domainurl.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM `domainurls` WHERE `domaindetail_id` = ? AND `count` = ?",@domain.id, cnt.count] #observe that I added @domain.id
```

You can rewrite that like

```
cnt = Domainurl.where(:domaindetail_id => @domain.id).maximum(:count) # this returns a number
urlcr=Domainurl.where("domaindetail_id = ? AND count = ?", @domain.id, cnt)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :)

for the below Query

**` cnt = Domainurl.where(:domaindetail_id => @domain.id).maximum(:count)
urlcr=Domainurl.where("domaindetail_id = ? AND count = ?", @domain.id, cnt.count) `**

still I am getting error:  

** ` "error is: undefined method `count' for 35:Fixnum" ` **

Comment: sorry for that, when I posted the first time I made a mistake, I edited the last query and instead of `cnt.count` now is just `cnt` because `maximum(:count)` return a number not an object